# Is it possible to decrypt cenc protected MPEG-DASH files?

Tags: c++, encryption, drm, mpeg-dash

What i have access to:

- (1) - .mp4 which contains the encrypted content
- (2) - .mpd

  pastebin.com/pM4n0R53

Is it possible to decrypt the .mp4 into a playable non-encrypted file using (1) & (2) only, if not, what's missing?

Comment: This doesn't appear to have anything to do with programming.  If you're hoping to achieve this programmatically, please tag the language you are using and edit your question to include your attempt at solving the problem.

Comment: You have to get license in order to encrypt those file - this is the basic of the DRM systems. After reading the mpd file the player should execute https call to the license-server and only with the response he can decrypt the media

Comment: @DavidWinder Is it possible to break through DRM, by grabbing the license response?

Comment: Why do you mean by grabbing? man-in-the-middle? no. The license returned is for the specific device that made the request (whom inner id send in the request itself) .

Comment: @DavidWinder Do you think that people who break this protection operate at a stage after the player has received the license and decrypted the media

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to decrypt the file when all you have is the encrypted files without the decryption keys. That would defeat the whole point of encrypting them to being with. Sure, if you have the decryption key, getting the clear version of the files should be fairly easy.